# What is the difference between re.search and re.match?

Tags: python, regex, search, match, string-matching

What is the difference between the `search()` and `match()` functions in the Python `re` module?

I've read the [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=matching%20searching#search-vs-match) ([Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)), but I never seem to remember it.

Comment: The way I remember it is that "search" evokes the image in my mind of an explorer with binoculars searching off in to the distance, just like `search` will search to the end of the string off in the distance.

Answer (score 663, accepted):

`re.match` is anchored at the beginning of the string. That has nothing to do with newlines, so it is not the same as using `^` in the pattern.

As the [re.match documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) says:

> If zero or more characters at the
>   **beginning of string** match the regular expression pattern, return a
>   corresponding `MatchObject` instance.
>   Return `None` if the string does not
>   match the pattern; note that this is
>   different from a zero-length match.
>
> Note: If you want to locate a match
>   anywhere in string, use `search()`
>   instead.

`re.search` searches the entire string, as [the documentation says](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

> **Scan through string** looking for a
>   location where the regular expression
>   pattern produces a match, and return a
>   corresponding `MatchObject` instance.
>   Return `None` if no position in the
>   string matches the pattern; note that
>   this is different from finding a
>   zero-length match at some point in the
>   string.

So if you need to match at the beginning of the string, or to match the entire string use `match`. It is faster. Otherwise use `search`.

The documentation has a [specific section for `match` vs. `search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) that also covers multiline strings:

> Python offers two different primitive
>   operations based on regular
>   expressions: `match` checks for a match
>   **only at the beginning** of the string,
>   while `search` checks for a match
>   **anywhere** in the string (this is what
>   Perl does by default).
>
> Note that `match` may differ from `search`
>   even when using a regular expression
>   beginning with `'^'`: `'^'` matches only
>   at the start of the string, or in
>   `MULTILINE` mode also immediately
>   following a newline. The “`match`”
>   operation succeeds *only if the pattern
>   matches at the **start** of the string*
>   regardless of mode, or at the starting
>   position given by the optional `pos`
>   argument regardless of whether a
>   newline precedes it.

Now, enough talk. Time to see some example code:

```
# example code:
string_with_newlines = """something
someotherthing"""

import re

print re.match('some', string_with_newlines) # matches
print re.match('someother', 
               string_with_newlines) # won't match
print re.match('^someother', string_with_newlines, 
               re.MULTILINE) # also won't match
print re.search('someother', 
                string_with_newlines) # finds something
print re.search('^someother', string_with_newlines, 
                re.MULTILINE) # also finds something

m = re.compile('thing$', re.MULTILINE)

print m.match(string_with_newlines) # no match
print m.match(string_with_newlines, pos=4) # matches
print m.search(string_with_newlines, 
               re.MULTILINE) # also matches
```

Comment: What about strings containing newlines?

Comment: even with strings containing newlines, match() matches only at the BEGINNING of the string.

Comment: That's the answer I was hoping for!  (Especially now that you provided an example.)

Comment: Why would anyone use limited `match` rather than more general `search` then? is it for speed?

Comment: @Alby match is much faster than search, so instead of doing regex.search("word") you can do regex.match((.*?)word(.*?)) and gain tons of performance if you are working with millions of samples.

Comment: Well, that's goofy. Why call it `match`? Is it a clever maneuver to seed the API's with unintuitive names to force me to read the documentation? I still won't do it! Rebel!

Comment: @ivan_bilan `match` looks a bit `faster` than search when using the same regular expression but your example seems wrong according to a performance test: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match/49710946#49710946

Comment: When using a regular expression beginning with '^', and with ```MULTILINE``` unspecified, is ```match``` the same as ```search``` (produce the same result)?

Comment: @Sammaron:   `search` searches in the string for the pattern, and `match` sees if the (entire) string matches the pattern.   I don't find this entirely unintituitive.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: `match` sees if the string *begins* with the pattern. It doesn't have to match the whole string. The `fullmatch` method (introduced much later) is the only one that requires the pattern to match the whole string (by anchoring at both beginning and end).

Comment: Why is match not named match_start or something? I want my 2 hours back!

Comment: They changed a lot of [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) in the most recent python3 versions since the last time I used it

Comment: @CarlChang yeah it's annoying

Answer (score 142):

`search` ⇒ find something anywhere in the string and return a match object.

`match` ⇒ find something at the *beginning* of the string and return a match object.

Answer (score 105):

> match is much faster than search, so instead of doing regex.search("word") you can do regex.match((.*?)word(.*?)) and gain tons of performance if you are working with millions of samples.

[This comment from @ivan_bilan under the accepted answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match#comment62326091_180993) got me thinking if such *hack* is actually speeding anything up, so let's find out how many tons of performance you will really gain.

I prepared the following test suite:

```
import random
import re
import string
import time

LENGTH = 10
LIST_SIZE = 1000000

def generate_word():
    word = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(LENGTH)]
    word = ''.join(word)
    return word

wordlist = [generate_word() for _ in range(LIST_SIZE)]

start = time.time()
[re.search('python', word) for word in wordlist]
print('search:', time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
[re.match('(.*?)python(.*?)', word) for word in wordlist]
print('match:', time.time() - start)
```

I made 10 measurements (1M, 2M, ..., 10M words) which gave me the following plot:

[image: match vs. search regex speedtest line plot]

As you can see, **searching for the pattern `'python'` is faster** than matching the pattern `'(.*?)python(.*?)'`.

*Python is smart. Avoid trying to be smarter.*

Comment: +1 for actually investigating the assumptions behind a statement meant to be taken at face value -- thanks.

Comment: Indeed the comment of @ivan_bilan looks wrong but the `match` function is still faster than the `search` function if you compare the same regular expression. You can check in your script by comparing `re.search('^python', word)` to `re.match('python', word)` (or `re.match('^python', word)` which is the same but easier to understand if you don't read the documentation and seems not to affect the performance)

Comment: @baptx I disagree with the statement that the `match` function is generally faster. The `match` is faster when you want to search **at the beginning** of the string, the `search` is faster when you want to search **throughout** the string. Which corresponds with the common sense. That's why @ivan_bilan was wrong - he used `match` to search throughout the string. That's why you are right - you used `match` to search at the beginning of the string. If you disagree with me, try to find regex for `match` that is faster than `re.search('python', word)` and does the same job.

Comment: @baptx Also, as a footnote, the `re.match('python')` **is** marginally faster than `re.match('^python')`. It has to be.

Comment: @Jeyekomon yes that's what I meant, `match` function is a bit faster if you want to search at the beginning of a string (compared to using `search` function to find a word at the beginning of a string with `re.search('^python', word)` for example). But I find this weird, if you tell the `search` function to search at the beginning of a string, it should be as fast as the `match` function.

Comment: @baptx My guess is that the `search` function has to parse and process the `^` information while `match` has it already hardcoded down in the c binary. The speed difference is only about 10 % on my PC anyway.

Comment: @Jeyekomon it could have come from here but I don't think it is the case since if we give the unnecessary `^` character to the `match` function, it does not take more time to read it (sometimes it was even a bit faster).

Comment: That `re.search()` is faster for this specific regex is not surprising at all. The `re.match()` pattern is longer to process if only because it's capturing the beginning of the string.

Comment: What about the library regex, is it faster than re?

Comment: @skan The `regex` library is not really on-topic here. You should create a new question for that.

Answer (score 59):

`re.search` **search**es for the pattern **throughout the string**, whereas `re.match` does *not search* the pattern; if it does not, it has no other choice than to **match** it at start of the string.

Comment: Why match at start, but not till end of string (`fullmatch` in phyton 3.4)?

Answer (score 41):

You can refer the below example to understand the working of `re.match` and re.search

```
a = "123abc"
t = re.match("[a-z]+",a)
t = re.search("[a-z]+",a)
```

`re.match` will return `none`, but `re.search` will return `abc`.

Comment: Would just like to add that search will return _sre.SRE_Match object (or None if not found). To get 'abc', you need to call t.group()

Answer (score 40):

The difference is, **`re.match()` misleads anyone accustomed to *Perl*, *grep*, or *sed* regular expression matching, and `re.search()` does not.** :-)

More soberly, [As John D. Cook remarks](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/python_regex/), `re.match()` "behaves as if every pattern has ^ prepended."  In other words, `re.match('pattern')` equals `re.search('^pattern')`.  So it anchors a pattern's left side.  But it also *doesn't anchor a pattern's right side:* that still requires a terminating `$`.

Frankly given the above, I think `re.match()` should be deprecated.  I would be interested to know reasons it should be retained.

Comment: "behaves as if every pattern has ^ prepended." is only true if you don't use the multiline option.  The correct statement is "... has \A prepended"

Answer (score 23):

Much shorter:

- `search` scans through the whole string.
- `match` scans only the beginning of the string.

Following Ex says it:

```
>>> a = "123abc"
>>> re.match("[a-z]+",a)
None
>>> re.search("[a-z]+",a)
abc
```

Comment: Even with most of the examples posted here, I am having a hard time seeing the description 'beginning of the string' as an accurate statement. I don't know, it just seems arbitrary. How do I know where the beginning of the string 'ends'?? Is it via a newline? because based from the example here, 'beginning' simply means the very first character '1'.

Answer (score 20):

re.match attempts to match a pattern **at the beginning of the string**. re.search attempts to match the pattern **throughout the string** until it finds a match.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer**

```
re.search('test', ' test')      # returns a Truthy match object (because the search starts from any index) 

re.match('test', ' test')       # returns None (because the search start from 0 index)
re.match('test', 'test')        # returns a Truthy match object (match at 0 index)
```

Answer (score 1):

`re.match` is anchored at the beginning of a string, while `re.search` scans through the entire string. So in the following example, `x` and `y` match the same thing.

```py
x = re.match('pat', s)       # <--- already anchored at the beginning of string
y = re.search('\Apat', s)    # <--- match at the beginning
```

If a string doesn't contain line breaks, `\A` and `^` are essentially the same; the difference shows up in multiline strings. In the following example, `re.match` will never match the second line, while `re.search` can with the correct regex (and flag).

```py
s = "1\n2"
re.match('2', s, re.M)       # no match
re.search('^2', s, re.M)     # match
re.search('\A2', s, re.M)    # no match  <--- mimics `re.match`
```

There's another function in `re`, `re.fullmatch()` that scans the entire string, so it is anchored both at the beginning and the end of a string. So in the following example, `x`, `y` and `z` match the same thing.

```py
x = re.match('pat\Z', s)     # <--- already anchored at the beginning; must match end
y = re.search('\Apat\Z', s)  # <--- match at the beginning and end of string
z = re.fullmatch('pat', s)   # <--- already anchored at the beginning and end
```

---

Based on [Jeyekomon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710946/19123103) (and using their setup), using the perfplot library, I plotted the results of timeit tests that looks into:

- how do they compare if `re.search` "mimics" `re.match`? (first plot)
- how do they compare if `re.match` "mimics" `re.search`? (second plot)
- how do they compare if the same pattern is passed to them? (last plot)

Note that the last pattern doesn't produce the same output (because `re.match` is anchored at the beginning of a string.)

[image: performance plot]

The first plot shows `match` is faster if `search` is used like `match`. The second plot supports @Jeyekomon's answer and shows `search` is faster if `match` is used like `search`. The last plot shows there's very little difference between the two if they scan for the same pattern.

---

Code used to produce the performance plot.

```py
import re
from random import choices
from string import ascii_lowercase
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from perfplot import plot

patterns = [
    [re.compile(r'\Aword'), re.compile(r'word')],
    [re.compile(r'word'), re.compile(r'(.*?)word')],
    [re.compile(r'word')]*2
]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20,6), facecolor='white')
for i, (pat1, pat2) in enumerate(patterns):
    plt.sca(axs[i])
    perfplot.plot(
        setup=lambda n: [''.join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=10)) for _ in range(n)],
        kernels=[lambda lst: [*map(pat1.search, lst)], lambda lst: [*map(pat2.match, lst)]],
        labels= [f"re.search(r'{pat1.pattern}', w)", f"re.match(r'{pat2.pattern}', w)"],
        n_range=[2**k for k in range(24)],
        xlabel='Length of list',
        equality_check=None
    )
fig.suptitle('re.match vs re.search')
fig.tight_layout();
```