# Regex Getting everything in between, Python

Tags: python, regex, wxpython, wxwidgets

Why is this regex not working?

```
import re
i="<wx._controls.Button; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxButton *' at 0x2d040b0> >"
m = re.match("controls(.*)[;]", i)
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

It returns nothing. I am trying to get everything in between, "controls" and ";"
This solution works with other test cases however not with this one.

Comment: Read this [What is the difference between Python's re.search and re.match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) only matches at the beginning of the string.  You want [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search).

However, it looks like you're evaluating the result of `repr` on an object to get the class name.  Why not just use `obj.__class__.__name__` instead?  On use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and avoid code specific to individual classes.

Answer (score 4):

`.match()` looks from the beginning. You want `.search()`.