# changing plaintext tags into HTML tags to display in browser in python

Tags: python, markup

ok so I'm writing a function in python which takes a text document which is tagged with tags like ===, ==, ---, #text# etc. etc. (alot like wikipedia). Now my program basically has to replace those with HTML tags such as &ndash, &mdash, <>text etc. so that they can be displayed properly in a browser. This is what i've got so far:

```
def tag_change ():
    for () in range ()
    sub('--', '&ndash;')
    sub('---', '&mdash;')
    sub('''*''', '<i>*</i>')
    sub("'''*'''", '<b>*</b>')
    sub("==*==", "<h1>*</h1>")
    sub("#*#", "<li>*</li>")
```

Am I on the right track? Or is there something else I need to include? I'm fairly new to this

Comment: Are you sure you want to implement "yet another markup format"? If you use an established one (e.g. [restructured text](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html) you can use existing tools to format it.

Comment: i don't mind which way i do it as long as i dont have to import a new module. which direction should i go if i use restructred text?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about the goal you are trying to achieve? Implement it as a learning experience, build a documentation tool, a blogging platform?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet (if you want to write your own function and avoid using an existing tool) is to use regex, which is simple enough

```
import re

def subst(text):
   str = '#text#'
   capture = re.search('#(.+)#', str)
   return '<li>'+ capture.group(1)+ '</li>'
```

I hope you get the idea
you could also use patterns like '==(.+)==' and so forth to capture what you want.
You can  view this post to learn more about using re.search and re.match
https://stackoverflow.com/a/180993/2152321

You can also learn more about regex pattern construction here
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm