# How do I return a string from a regex match in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am running through lines in a text file using a `python` script.
I want to search for an `img` tag within the text document and return the tag as text.

When I run the regex `re.match(line)` it returns a  `_sre.SRE_MATCH` object.
How do I get it to return a string?

```
import sys
import string
import re

f = open("sample.txt", 'r' )
l = open('writetest.txt', 'w')

count = 1

for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    imgtag  = re.match(r'<img.*?>',line)
    print("yo it's a {}".format(imgtag))
```

When run it prints:

```
yo it's a None
yo it's a None
yo it's a None
yo it's a <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd4ea90e578>
yo it's a None
yo it's a <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd4ea90e578>
yo it's a None
yo it's a <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd4ea90e578>
yo it's a <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd4ea90e5e0>
yo it's a None
yo it's a None
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You should use `re.MatchObject.group(0)`. Like

```
imtag = re.match(r'<img.*?>', line).group(0)
```

Edit:

You also might be better off doing something like

```
imgtag  = re.match(r'<img.*?>',line)
if imtag:
    print("yo it's a {}".format(imgtag.group(0)))
```

to eliminate all the `None`s.

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects

Comment: I tried the code as shown above, but got the return value of None. If I changed the ' method to 'search' instead of 'match' I got the expected result. Not sure why this is...?

Comment: [Match is anchored to the start of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match).

Comment: `imgtag.group()` without indexes also works

Answer (score 11):

`imgtag.group(0)` or `imgtag.group()`.  This returns the entire match as a string.  You are not capturing anything else either.

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/match-objects.html

Answer (score 10):

Note that `re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)` only returns matches at the *beginning* of the string. If you want to locate a match *anywhere* in the string, use **`re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`** instead (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). This will scan the string and return the first match object. Then you can extract the matching string with `match_object.group(0)` as the folks suggested.

Answer (score 8):

Considering there might be several `img` tags I would recommend `re.findall`:

```
import re

with open("sample.txt", 'r') as f_in, open('writetest.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        for img in re.findall('<img[^>]+>', line):
            print >> f_out, "yo it's a {}".format(img)
```