# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and '_sre.SRE_Match' objects

Tags: python, regex, concatenation

I'm retrieving a string with regex, and I'm trying to concatenate that with other pieces of string.

Error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and '_sre.SRE_Match' objects
```

Example:

```
original_string = "ABC 4x DEF"
regex = re.search(r"(\d)X|x", original_string)
new_string = "+" + regex + "00"
print "New string: %s" % new_string
```

`new_string` should be `"+400"` if everything works.

Comment: Your posted code does not define any variable called `regex_fundleverage`.  Have you read [the documnetation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to understand what match objects are, where you get them, and how to use them?

Comment: Can see more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493677/how-do-i-return-a-string-from-a-regex-match-in-python

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry, edited. It should just be variable `regex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`regex` is not a string. It is a [*Match Object*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) representing the match. You'll have to pull the matched text:

```
fundleverage = "+" + regex.group(1) + "0"
```

Note that your expression matches either a digit with a capital `X` **or** it matches a lowercase `x` (no digit). In your case that means it matched the `x`, and group 1 is empty (`None`)..

To match the digit and either `x` or `X`, use:

```
regex = re.search(r"(\d)[Xx]", original_string)
```

or use case-insensitive matching:

```
regex = re.search(r"(\d)x", original_string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> original_string = "ABC 4x DEF"
>>> regex = re.search(r"(\d)X|x", original_string)
>>> regex
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10696ecd8>
>>> regex.group()
'x'
>>> regex.groups()
(None,)
>>> regex = re.search(r"(\d)x", original_string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> regex.group()
'4x'
>>> regex.groups()
('4',)
>>> regex.group(1)
'4'
```

Answer (score 2):

For case insensitive match, use `(?i)`.

```
original_string = "ABC 4x DEF"
regex = re.search(r"(\d)x(?i)", original_string)
new_string = "+" + regex.group() + "00"
print "New string: %s" % new_string
```

New string: +4x00