# return date string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to return the date from a longer string. The date could be any weekday, any number with a subscript `st, nd, rd, th` and the month as 3 string values `(Jan, Feb etc)`.

This is my attempt but I'm getting None. Not sure what I'm missing?

```
string = 'Times for Saturday 10th Aug'

days = ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')
months = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
pat = re.compile(r'^(%s) (\d+)(st|nd|rd|th) (%s)$' %
                 ('|'.join(days), '|'.join(months)))

print(re.match(pat, string))
```

Comment: `^` means the start of line. What happens when you remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A caret `^` in a regex and `re.match` both start matching at the start of the string. Simply remove the caret and use `re.search` instead.

```
pat = re.compile(r'(%s) (\d+)(st|nd|rd|th) (%s)$' %
                 ('|'.join(days), '|'.join(months)))

print(re.search(pat, string))
```

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea. I want to pass the date string to another call function. It's returning `<re.Match object; span=(88, 105), match='Saturday 10th Aug'>`. I'm only after `Saturday 10th Aug`

Comment: @jonboy See [How do I return a string from a regex match in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18493677/4518341)

Comment: Cheers. Thanks @wjandrea

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the beginning of line character `^` and the end of the line character `$`, then everything works just fine:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(%s) (\d+)(st|nd|rd|th) (%s)' %
...                  ('|'.join(days), '|'.join(months)), string)
[('Saturday', '10', 'th', 'Aug')]
```

And, please, don't call variable `string` -- it's already used in python.