# Regex to find last word in a string (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a simple regex that finds if the last word in the string is a specific one.

I wrote something like this `"(\W|^)dog$"`. (Check if last word in the sentence is dog)

This regex is correct but in python it is returning nothing when i type something like `"I like dog"`.

I tested this in the Rubular regex editor and it seems to work.

Am I doing something wrong ?

EDIT : Adding my simple code

```
import re
pm = re.compile("(\W|^)dog$")
has = pm.match("i love dog")
print(has)
```

Comment: Are your words always space separated?

Comment: Post your python code.

Comment: Yes. NO hypenated word required> Also FYI I tried ( |^)dog$ with same result !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Python's re.search and re.match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match)

Comment: `df.str.replace(r"(\W|^)(dog|cat)$", ' ')` this worked for a list of terms in python pandas

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to regex here. Simple split will do the job:

```
>>> s = "I like dog"
>>> s.rsplit(None, 1)[-1] == 'dog'
True
```

Since you need the last word only, [`str.rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) can be used to start splitting from end, and passing `1` as 2nd argument, will only perform split only once. Then get the last element of the returned list.

---

As for doing this with regex, you would need to use `re.search` method, instead of `re.match` method. The later one matches at the beginning of the string, so you would need to build the regex to match the entire string. You can rather do:

```
pm = re.compile(r"\bdog$")
has = pm.search("i love dog")
```

`\b` is word boundary. [**See Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/bglHgO).

To do the same with `re.match`, your regex should be - `r".*dog$"`.

```
pm = re.compile(r".*dog$")
has = pm.match("i love dog")
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jain. But this simple regex is my way of revising regular expressions for upcoming interviews and hence I am interested to know how to do it via python.

Comment: @rajaditya_m You should use `re.search` method instead of `re.match`.

Comment: Awesome. I just changed the match to search in my OLD regex and it also works. (In this case atleast).

Comment: `r".*dog"` would match stuff like 'asdfasdfdog', no? The word boundary might still be desired.

Comment: I the question was about the regex and not the alter solutions, so i't is good to know what the regex is for this case

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight modification of your code (that works):

```
import re
pm = re.compile(r'.*\b(dog)$')
has = pm.match("i love dog")
print(has)
```

The regex `.*\b(dog)$` maches anything (`.*`) then a word boundry (`\b`) and then your word (`dog`) and then the end of the line (`$`). Which is exactly what you want. Live demo [**here**](http://codepad.org/zrUjHTjx).

Answer (score 1):

Get the word at the end of the string. Whatever that word is.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+)$")
has = pm.search("i love dog")
print has.group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
import re
text = "Python was conceived in the late 1980"
s = re.findall(r"\s(\w+)$", text)
print(s)
```

Or

```
s = re.split("\s", text)
print(s[-1])
```