# Python regex findall works but match does not

Tags: python, regex

I'm testing this in IPython.  The variable `t` is being set from text in a dictionary and returns:

```
u'http://www.amazon.com/dp/B003T0G9GM/ref=wl_it_dp_v_nS_ttl/177-5611794-0982247?_encoding=UTF8&colid=SBGZJRGMR8TA&coliid=I205LCXDIRSLL3'
```

using this code:

```
r = r'amazon\.com/dp/(\w{10})' 
m = re.findall(r,t)
```

matches correctly and `m` returns `[u'B003T0G9GM']`

Using this code,

```
p = re.compile(r)
m = p.match(t)
```

`m` returns `None`

This appears correct to me after reading this documentation.
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping

I also tested here to verify the regex before trying this in IPython
http://regex101.com/r/gG8eQ2/1

What am I missing?

Comment: `match` matches from the beginning of the string, you probably need `search` instead. See [What is the difference between Python's re.search and re.match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SHould be using [search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match), not match. This is what you should have:

```
p = re.compile(r)
m = p.search(t)
if m: print(m.group(1)) # gives: B003T0G9GM
```

Match checks only the begining of string. Search goes over whole string.