# Python regex match middle of string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a python string, that I'm trying to extract. I have a interesting issue:

```
>>> s="SKU 9780136058281, (ASIN B00A2KNZ2S, (binding Merchant: 'paperback' / 'hardcover'))"
>>> print(re.match('ASIN', s))
None
>>> print(re.match('SKU', s))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='SKU'>
```

I'm trying to mach a the number after ASIN. I can't still see a obvious problem.  Its matching the beginning of the line, but not in the middle.

Comment: `match` matches the beginning! `search` matches in the middle of the string!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`re.match` tries to match the pattern **from beginning** of the string/text/etc. Instead, you need to use `re.search` and [grouping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

```
>>> s="SKU 9780136058281, (ASIN B00A2KNZ2S, (binding Merchant: 'paperback' / 'hardcover'))"
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'SKU (\d+)',s).group(1)
'9780136058281'
```

`r'SKU (\d+)` will match any combination of digits (`\d`) with length 1 or more that came after `SKU` and a space!