# Why have re.match()?

Tags: python, regex

I know this topic has already been discussed [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346076/python-re-match-vs-re-search) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match) here on StackOverflow, but I'm looking for a better answer.

While I appreciate the [differences](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match), I was not really able to find a definitive explanation of *why* the `re` module in python provides both `match()` and `search()`.
Couldn't I get the same behavior with `search()`, if I prepend `^` in single line mode, and `/A` in multiline mode? Am I missing anything?

I tried to understand the implementation looking at the [_sre.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1c45047c5102/Modules/_sre.c) code and I understand that the search (`sre_search()`) is actually implemented moving the pointer in the string to be searched, and applying the `sre_match()` on it, until a match is found.

So I guess that using the `re.match()` might be slightly faster than the corresponding regular expression (with `^`  or `/A`) using the `re.search()`. Is that the reason?

I also researched the python-dev ML archives but to no avail.

```
>>> string="""first line
... second line"""
>>> print re.match('first', string, re.MULTILINE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1072ae7e8>
>>> print re.match('second', string, re.MULTILINE)
None
>>> print re.search('\Afirst', string, re.MULTILINE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1072ae7e8>
>>> print re.search('\Asecond', string, re.MULTILINE)
None
```

Comment: A quick try actually suggests that `match` is slower: http://pastebin.com/VABXxY3H

Comment: @vks no, `re.match(r'[\s\S]*', "foo\nbar").group()`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.`  https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: yep,, it starts matching the string from start.

Comment: @vks yes but `re.match('abc', string, re.MULTILINE)` is equivalent to `re.search('\Aabc', string, re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: @spider that is what....if you dont want such sort of behaviour which `re.match` has you need `re.search` right?

Comment: It's mainly convenience I suppose. While you can use `re.search`, generally `re.match` is what a lot of people need.

Comment: Also don't underestimate the improvement of readablility... ruby for example has even introduced the keyword `unless` which is basically `if not` only to make it easier to understand the code.

Comment: Might be a bit polemic but if you go crazy about it you could also ask yourself what the `+` is good for if you can have the same functionality with `--`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already know, `re.match` will test the pattern only at the start of the string and `re.search` will test all the string until it find a match.

So, is there a difference between `re.match('toto', s)` and `re.search('^toto', s)` and what it is?

Lets make a little test:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import re

p1 = re.compile(r'toto')
p2 = re.compile(r'^toto')

ssize = 1000

s1 = 'toto abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012356789'*ssize
s2 = 'titi abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012356789'*ssize

nb = 1000

i = 0
t0 = time.time()
while i < nb:
    p1.match(s1)
    i += 1
t1 = time.time()

i = 0
t2 = time.time()
while i < nb:
    p2.search(s1)
    i += 1
t3 = time.time()

print "\nsucceed\nmatch:"
print (t1-t0)
print "search:"
print (t3-t2)


i = 0
t0 = time.time()
while i < nb:
    p1.match(s2)
    i += 1
t1 = time.time()

i = 0
t2 = time.time()
while i < nb:
    p2.search(s2)
    i += 1
t3 = time.time()

print "\nfail\nmatch:"
print (t1-t0)
print "search:"
print (t3-t2)
```

The two ways are tested with a string that doesn't match and a string that matches.

results:

```
succeed
match:
0.000469207763672
search:
0.000494003295898

fail
match:
0.000430107116699
search:
0.46605682373
```

What can we conclude with these results:

1) The performances are similar when the pattern succeeds

2) The performances are totally different when the pattern fails. This is the most important point because, it means that **`re.search` continues to test each positions of the string even if the pattern is anchored** when `re.match` stops immediatly.

If you increase the size of the failing test string, you will see that `re.match` doesn't take more time but `re.search` depends of the string size.

Comment: That's interesting. I tried with both 2.7 and 3.4 and the behaviour is the one you described. Now I'm also more curious, I'll dig a bit more into it, i.e. better looking at the implementation.

Comment: @spider: I'm not sure that this will reveal you more things, especially since there is clearly a linear relation between the time and the failing string size with the `re.search` method when the time is constant with the `re.match` method.

Comment: Casimir I mean that I'm curious to find understand the differences in the two implementations. For the sake of improving my knowledge. I accepted your answer, btw.

Comment: This is not a convincing answer imo, because `re.search` could be optimized not to continue needless searching when there's ^ in the pattern. The fact it hasn't been given such an optimization seems just implementation detail, that's not a particularly good reason for `re.match` to exist.