# Regex for number extraction not working in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/lW3pJ0/1)

But running it in the python2.7 it gives `None`, why is that?

```
>>> fo = re.match('\.(\d+)\.', '/players/player.34360.html')
>>> type(fo)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.match()` only matches at the beginning of the string. Use `re.search`:

```
fo = re.search(r'\.(\d+)\.', r'/players/player.34360.html')
```

**A hint**: in [regex101.com](http://regex101.com), you can get code snippets in Python, PHP and JavaScript, by clicking on the `code generator` link on the left. You could see at once that for Python, you should use `search`.

Comment: What is the use case of `match`?

Comment: When you want to match something at the beginning of the string, but do not want to use `^` in the pattern itself, as perhaps, you will need to use the regex later to search for all occurrences.