# Regular expression: Match everything after a particular word

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python and would like to match all the words after `test` till a period (full-stop) or space is encountered.

```
text = "test : match this."
```

At the moment, I am using :

```
import re
re.match('(?<=test :).*',text)
```

The above code doesn't match anything. I need `match this` as my output.

Comment: Is your expression not working correctly? If that's the case, please provide the output that it's producing.

Comment: And please specify what output you expect: " match", " match this" or "match this". Please tell us how exactly it does not work.

Comment: Well, what I am using doesnt work :-)

Comment: Do you want to match a specific subset of words? because if you just want to extract all the words after test you can use subsetting.

Comment: You need to use `re.search`. as usual match tries to match from the begining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why you want to use regex if you're just getting a subset from a string.

This works the same way:

```
if line.startswith('test:'):
    print(line[5:line.find('.')])
```

example:

```
>>> line = "test: match this."
>>> print(line[5:line.find('.')])
 match this
```

Regex is slow, it is awkward to design, and difficult to debug. There are definitely occassions to use it, but if you just want to extract the text between `test:` and `.`, then I don't think is one of those occasions.

See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions

For more flexibility (for example if you are looping through a list of strings you want to find at the beginning of a string and then index out) replace 5 (the length of 'test:') in the index with `len(str_you_looked_for)`.

Comment: I completely agree. I normally try to avoid regex as much as possible. But I need to match a lot of other strings in a large number of web pages.

Comment: Are they different? Can they not be seen in a similar way?

Comment: Just went through the link you provided. Very interesting. You have made me reconsider my approach!!

Comment: @Amith I agree, no strings attached :) I myself like to provide 2 solutions, regex-based and non-regex based. No need this time.

Comment: @Amith, no problem. Regex is one of those things that is really easy to abuse.

Comment: Hate to revive an old thread. But why is this marked as the answer? The question asks for REGEX. When people search for this specific topic and this question shows up with an unrelated answer it wastes their time.

Comment: Because the person who asked the question decided it best fit their problem. Whilst I appreciate the comment and agree, for some the regex by avinash may be better suited, that doesn't make it an invalid or worse answer for many others.

I would also ask why anyone thinks regex would be better suited for this problem? (find the text appearing after another specific piece of text)

Answer (score 51):

Everything after test, including test

```
test.*
```

Everything after test, without test

```
(?<=test).*
```

[Example here on regexr.com](https://regexr.com/3laj6)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, fast and simple

Answer (score 19):

You need to use re.search since `re.match` tries to match from the beging of the string. To match until a space or period is encountered.

```
re.search(r'(?<=test :)[^.\s]*',text)
```

To match all the chars until  a period is encountered,

```
re.search(r'(?<=test :)[^.]*',text)
```

Answer (score 6):

In a general case, as the title mentions, you may *capture* with `(.*)` pattern any 0 or more chars other than newline after any pattern(s) you want:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'test\s*:\s*(.*)')
s = "test : match this."
m = p.search(s)           # Run a regex search anywhere inside a string
if m:                     # If there is a match
    print(m.group(1))     # Print Group 1 value
```

If you want `.` to match across multiple lines, compile the regex with `re.DOTALL` or `re.S` flag (or add `(?s)` before the pattern):

```
p = re.compile(r'test\s*:\s*(.*)', re.DOTALL)
p = re.compile(r'(?s)test\s*:\s*(.*)')
```

However, [it will retrun `match this.`](https://ideone.com/yB2Vbp). See also a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hPjQHV/1).

You can add `\.` pattern after `(.*)` to make the regex engine stop before the last `.` on that line:

```
test\s*:\s*(.*)\.
```

[**Watch out for `re.match()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match) since it will only look for a match at the beginning of the string (Avinash aleady pointed that out, but it is a very important note!)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM2rX1/10) and a [sample Python code snippet](https://ideone.com/0KD8Ik):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'test\s*:\s*(.*)\.')
s = "test : match this."
m = p.search(s)           # Run a regex search anywhere inside a string
if m:                     # If there is a match
    print(m.group(1))     # Print Group 1 value
```

If you want to make sure `test` is matched as a whole word, add `\b` before it (do not remove the `r` prefix from the string literal, or `'\b'` will match a BACKSPACE char!) - `r'\btest\s*:\s*(.*)\.'`.