# Getting incorrect match while using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to find if a link contains ".pdf" at its end.

I am skipping all the characters before ".pdf" using `[/w/-]+` in regular expression and then seeing if it contains ".pdf". I am new to regular expressions.

The code is:

```
import urllib2
import json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://codex.cs.yale.edu/avi/os-book/OS8/os8c/slide-dir/"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read())
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    name = link.get("href")
    if(re.match(r'[\w/.-]+.pdf',name)):
        print name
```

I want to match name with following type of links:

> PDF-dir/ch1.pdf

Comment: What do you think `[/b/-]+` does?

Comment: Do you want all result containing ".pdf" or just one. If you want all, maybe you should use search instead of match.

Comment: It matches one or more occurences of  [a-zA-Z0-9_/-]

Comment: Have you tried just '.pdf' ？

Comment: I have tried. It won't match.

Comment: @yobichi: only one ".pdf" at the last of link.

Comment: 1. `for links in links` is bad and will surely cause problems. 2. Have you tried a simple `os.path.splitext`?

Comment: Try `re.search()` instead of `re.match()`

Comment: @RohanAmrute That will find all the ".pdf". It will also return true if link = "www.pdfsite.com".

Comment: Ok, so, why not use the pattern like `re.search(r'[\w-]+/[\w-]+\.pdf$',name)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small change in your code

```
for link in links:
name = link.get("href")
if(re.search(r'\.pdf$',name)):
    print name
```

The output is like:

> PDF-dir/ch1.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch2.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch3.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch4.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch5.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch6.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch7.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch8.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch9.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch10.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch11.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch12.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch13.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch14.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch15.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch16.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch17.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch18.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch19.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch20.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch21.pdf
>   PDF-dir/ch22.pdf
>   PDF-dir/appA.pdf
>   PDF-dir/appC.pdf

Comment: Since he only wants '.pdf' at the end, it's better to do: if(re.search(r'\.pdf$',name))

Comment: This code works. But I am asking why my original code doesn't work?

Comment: Refer to this link, difference between `re.search()` and `re.match()`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match

Comment: @ShivamMitra Basically `re.match()` attempts to match a pattern at the **beginning** of the string. `re.search()` attempts to match the pattern **throughout** the string until it finds a match.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regular expressions. Use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to check that an `href` *ends with `pdf`*:

```
for link in soup.select("a[href$=pdf]"):
    print(link["href"])
```