# regex extract domain from anywhere in string using python

Tags: python, regex

How do i match a domain from each of the strings below using python regex. In this case s1 is invalid becaulse .local is not a good valid tld

```
s1 = '220 Exng-CAS1.aldanube.local Microsoft , 16 Feb 2016 14:52:24 +0400' # ignore this

# catch all this 
s2 = '220 mail6.mithi.com' 
s3 = '220 news-letter.music.jp unknown'
s3 = '220 nice .music.co.uk Welcome to the server. 16 Feb 2016 14:52:24 +0400'

>>> import re
>>> r = re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.', s1)
>>> r.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between Python's re.search and re.match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match)

Comment: try `r.group()` not `re.group`, aka `r = re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.', s1).group()` which further returns none, since `re.match` tries to match from the begining.

Comment: You need to compile a list of _good, valid_ TLDs first.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it is a typo. fixed it

Comment: @JideKoso use this `(?<=\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+` regex and check the match against the list of valid domain names.