# Python regex dealing with "?"

Tags: python, regex

I know it's a pretty simple question. I happened to look at a regex example.

```
import re
pattern = r'^M?M?M?$'

s = "MDM"

re.search(pattern, s)
```

May I know why it doesn't match the string `s`? AFAIK, `?` is to specify 0 or 1 occurence. It matches MMM though.

However the same string matches when the pattern is `r'M?M?M?$'` or `r'^M?M?M?'`. I am not getting what makes the difference here. Could someone please explain?

Comment: The `^` and `$` anchors together make the whole difference. The whole string must match.

Comment: `M?` is : M or nothing . so `D` does not match.

Comment: that pattern can only match first M, and regex evaluation hit $, so it does not match.

Comment: `?` is a special character in python regex https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: consider `^M{0,3}$`, will it match MDM? no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r'^M?M?M?$'` is the same as `r'^M{0,3}$'`. So, your pattern accepts `'', 'M', 'MM', 'MMM'` strings.

`r'M?M?M?$'` is the same as `r'M{0,3}$` and, actually, accepts all strings, since there is always an empty part at the end of the string:

```
In [21]: pattern = r'M?M?M?$'

In [22]: re.search(pattern, 'A string without capital m at all')
Out[22]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(33, 33), match=''>
```

Comment: Nice. I didnt get this part though "actually, accepts all strings, since there is always an empty part at the end of the string:"

Comment: Got it!!..Since we dont mention the beginning of a string, any string might end with 0 or 1 "M"s. Thats why it matches any string. Is that what u meant?

Comment: @DineshKumar, exactly

Answer (score 1):

The regex

```
M?M?M?$
```

matches the last "M" in "MDM". But when you add `^` (beginning of string), it'll try to match from the beginning and it'll fail because `M?` matches 0 or 1 "M", but not a "D".

On the other regex:

```
^M?M?M?
```

The first "M" is matched.

Comment: Your explanation *`search` looks in the whole string, not from the beginning* does not sound right. It does search for a match from the beginning, but the match does not have to start at the beginning.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there's `match` and `search` in Python. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match) , that's what I tried to say, maybe I have to make it clearer a bit.

Comment: I know the difference very well. It does not mean the `re.search` does not search for a match from the beginning of a string. Otherwise, `^M?` would not match the first `M`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It *does* look, but as opposed to `match`, it doesn't attempt to match from the string beginning.

Answer (score 1):

`^` matches the start of a line. `$` matches the end of the line.

so `'M?M?M?$'` matches the last `M` in `MDM` and `'^M?M?M?'` matches the first `M` in `MDM`.

`'^M?M?M?$'` cannot match `MDM` because of the `D` in the middle that is not listed in your regex and the requirement to match the start of the line and the end of the line while there are 0, 1, 2 or 3 `M` in between.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "the requirement to match the start of the line and the end of the line while there are 0, 1, 2 or 3 M in between." this statement nailed it.