# Parsing string in python3 using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to parse string which has length & precision in it eg:'(10,2)' and I need to take out length & precision.

Need output as:

_len = 10, 
 _pre = 2

I tried below but it's not working,

```
>>> import re
>>> my_str = 'numeric(10,2)'
>>> m = re.match(r'\d+,\d+', my_str)
>>> m
>>> m = re.match(r'(\d+,\d+)', my_str)
>>> m
>>> m = re.match('\((+d),(+d)\)', my_str)
>>> m = re.match('\((+d),(+d)\)', my_str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Read this post for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match

Comment: And documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Comment: @Kasramvd Thanks for references, I'll defiantly refer them.

Answer (score 2):

`re.match` starts searching from the beginning of the line, that's why you are not getting any match.

Use `re.search` instead:

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(\d+),(\d+)', my_str)
>>> if m:
...     _len, _pre = map(int, m.groups())
... 
>>> _len, _pre
(10, 2)
```

Comment: You could use capturing groups in the regex to avoid the need for the split.

Comment: @DanielRoseman good suggestion