# Python regular expressions - get numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am new for Python. I have a file with the following content

```
#define VKU_BS_MAJOR_VERSION_S "2"
#define VKU_BS_MINOR_VERSION_S "0"
#define VKU_BS_BUILD_NUMBER_S "55"
```

And i want to extract 2, 0 and 55. After it I want to increment these values and write them back to the file. But I simply can't obtain them.

I tried this:

```
buildInfoFile = open(buildInfoFilePath, "r")
content = buildInfoFile.read()
buildMajorRegex = re.compile("VKU_BS_MAJOR_VERSION_S \"(\\d+)\"", re.MULTILINE)
match = buildMajorRegex.match(content);
print(match)
```

Which prints

> None

But I've checked my regular expression at regex101 and it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

And also - what is the best way to increment the values and put them back to 'content'?

Comment: you are confusing match with search

Comment: `match` looks for a match starting at the *beginning* of the line; you might want to try the `search` method instead.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360740/regex-working-on-regex101-not-working-with-python, which was closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using `regular expressions` and `findall`.

```
import re

s1 = '#define VKU_BS_MAJOR_VERSION_S "2"'
s2 = '#define VKU_BS_MINOR_VERSION_S "55"'
s3 = '#define VKU_BS_B123UILD_N456UMBE789R_S "10"'

re.findall("\d+", s1)
#['2']

re.findall("\d+", s2)
#['55']

r.findall("\d+", s3)
#['123', '456', '789', '10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `match = buildMajorRegex.search(content)` instead and `match.group(1)` gives your figure.

To use `match`, your regex has to *match* the argument exactly, like so:

```
 buildMajorRegex = re.compile("#define VKU_BS_MAJOR_VERSION_S \"(\\d+)\"", re.MULTILINE)
 match = buildMajorRegex.match(content)
```

Comment: Yes, as @njzk2 suggested I tried search instead of match. And what is the best way to increment the value and put it back?

Comment: read all the lines into a `list` (already done by `open()`), capture the numerical figures (already done), increment, then replace the figure in its corresponding item in the list. Finally, you write back all the values back to the file; an overwrite should do.