# Why is the regex "java" not matching "/something.java" using Python's re module?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, match

This is the code:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('java')
print regex.match('/something.java')
```

This is the output:

> None

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match

Comment: Huh. Thought that was what the `^` symbol was for. Thanks, search worked.

Comment: Probable problem: `match` requires a whole string match, `search` will find substrings.

Comment: @sln  In Python, `re.match` only anchors the match at the start of the string.

Comment: Sorry @WiktorStribiżew I guess it's 'Probable problem: match requires a half string match'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because python match matches from the beginning. see 
[python -- re.match vs. re.search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346076/python-re-match-vs-re-search)
you need to use pattern `.*java` if you want to use match.