# using OR operator (|) in variable for regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to match against a list of string values. I'm using '|'.join() to build a sting that is passed into re.match:

```
import re
line='GigabitEthernet0/1 is up, line protocol is up'
interfacenames=[
                'Loopback',
                'GigabitEthernet'
                ]
rex="r'" + '|'.join(interfacenames) + "'"
print rex
interface=re.match(rex,line)
print interface
```

The code result is:

```
r'Loopback|GigabitEthernet'
None
```

However if I copy past the string directly into match:

```
interface=re.match(r'Loopback|GigabitEthernet',line)
```

It works:

```
r'Loopback|GigabitEthernet'
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fcdaf2f4718>
```

I did try to replace .join with actual "Loopback|GigabitEthernet" in rex and it didn't work either. It looks like the pipe symbol is not treated as operator when passed from string.
Any thoughts how to fix it?

Comment: the raw prefix is useless in that case. Problem is that your generated regex has simple quotes in it. Remove them: `rex = '|'.join(interfacenames)`

Comment: You didn't copy/paste the same string when you did your test. It would have to be `re.match("r'Loopback|GigabitEthernet'",line)`.

Comment: Thank you. Was sure I did try it at some point but clearly did something wrong. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You use the `r'` prefix as a part of a string literal. This is how it could be used:

```
rex=r'|'.join(interfacenames)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/IIXr4D)

If the *interfacenames* may contain special regex metacharacters, escape the values like this:

```
rex=r'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in interfacenames])
```

Also, if you plan to match the strings not only at the start of the string, use `re.search` rather than `re.match`. See [What is the difference between Python's re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put `"r'"` at the beginning and `"'"`. That's part of the syntax for literal raw strings, it's not part of the string itself.

```
rex = '|'.join(interfacenames)
```