# Python string must match beginning of regex but not end

Tags: python, regex, grep

I find this behavior slightly strange:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"test")
print pattern.match("testsda") is not None
True
print pattern.match("astest") is not None
False
```

So, when the string doesn't match the pattern at its end, everything is fine. But when the string doesn't match the pattern at its beginning, the string doesn't match the pattern anymore.

By comparison, grep succeeds in both cases:

```
echo "testsda" | grep  test
testsda
echo "adtest" | grep  test
adtest
```

Do you know why this is happening ?

Comment: have you read the documentation for `match`?

Comment: See also [What is the difference between Python's re.search and re.match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match)

Comment: @Bryan, obviously I didn't :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.match` is designed to only match at the start of a string. As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) state:

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of
>   the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default).

If you use `re.search`, you should be fine:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"test")
print pattern.search("testsda") is not None
print pattern.search("astest") is not None
```

prints

```
True
True
```