# Python Find entire word in string using regex and user input

Tags: python, regex, search

I'm trying to find the entire word exactly using regex but have the word i'm searching for be a variable value coming from user input. I've tried this:

```
regex = r"\b(?=\w)" + re.escape(user_input) + r"\b"
if re.match(regex, string_to_search[i], re.IGNORECASE):
      <some code>...
```

but it matches every occurrence of the string. It matches "var"->"var" which is correct but also matches "var"->"var"iable and I only want it to match "var"->"var" or "string"->"string"

Input: "sword"

String_to_search = "There once was a swordsmith that made a sword"

Desired output: Match "sword" to "sword" and not "swordsmith"

Comment: Please post your input and desired output.

Comment: Well, `\bvar\b` cannot match `var` in `variable`. Why are you using `re.match`? If you want to match user input as a whole string, you may use `regex = '{}$'.format(re.escape(user_input))` and then use `re.match()`. Else, if you need to really just find `var` as a whole word inside a larger string, you will need `re.search` with `\bvar\b` regex.

Comment: Doesn't python have a non regex function like a substring search ?

Comment: If python supported conditionals you could wrap it into conditional boundary's `(?(?=\w)\b)(?: your literal )(?(?<=\w)\b)` And this `\b(?=\w)` forces the literal to start with a `\w`

Comment: @sln yeah but it will find any substring including "var" in variable which i don't want. I'm going to try the .format or re.search and conditional

Comment: Or, you could do it without a conditional `(?:(?=\w)\b|(?=\W))(?:  your literal (?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<=\W))`

Comment: After your edit, it looks like your question is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution worked! thanks! I'll post the solution

Comment: What solution and why you if it is mine?

Comment: `value coming from user input` You know, if you think about it, the user shouldn't care _where_ the string is found right.  It's only _you_ who thinks they can parse language using word boundary's.. Word boundary's are problematic, use _whitespace boundary's_ `(?<!\S)(?: your literal )(?!\S)`. Doing the math now, that's 2 solutions I gave you that just didn't register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem you want to use a pattern that matches an entire string. Note that `\b` word boundary is needed when you wan to find partial matches. When you need a full string match, you need *anchors*. Since `re.match` anchors the match at the start of string, all you need is `$` (end of string position) at the end of the pattern:

```
regex = '{}$'.format(re.escape(user_input))
```

and then use

```
re.match(regex, search_string, re.IGNORCASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try re.finditer like that:

```
>>> import re
>>> user_input = "var"
>>> text = "var variable var variable"
>>> regex = r"(?=\b%s\b)" % re.escape(user_input)
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer(regex, text)]
[0, 13]
```

It'll find all matches iteratively.

Comment: Where is the output saved to in the loop? Because i would like to break on the first finding and say if it was found, do this, else, do that.

Comment: @E.Oregel then just put this into the loop like this: `for m in re.finditer(regex, text):` and to inside the loop what you want.