# Regex for parameter of a function

Tags: python, regex

I'm fairly inexperienced with regex, but I need one to match the parameter of a function. This function will appear multiple times in the string, and I would like to return a list of all parameters.

The regex must match:

1. Alphanumeric and underscore
2. Inside quotes directly inside parenthesis
3. After a specific function name

Here's an example string:

```
Generic3(p, [Generic3(g, [Atom('_xyx'), Atom('y'), Atom('z_')]), Atom('x_1'), Generic2(f, [Atom('x'), Atom('y')])])
```

and I would like this as output:

```
['_xyx', 'y', 'z_', x_1', 'x', 'y']
```

What I have so far:

```
(?<=Atom\(')[\w|_]*
```

I'm calling this with:

import re

```
s = "Generic3(p, [Generic3(g, [Atom('x'), Atom('y'), Atom('z')]), Atom('x'), Generic2(f, [Atom('x'), Atom('y')])])"
print(re.match(r"(?<=Atom\(')[\w|_]*", s))
```

But this just prints `None`. I feel like I'm nearly there, but I'm missing something, maybe on the Python side to actually return the matches.

Comment: Maybe `re.findall(r"(?<=Atom\(')\w+", s)`? Or with [`r"Atom\('(\w+)"`](https://ideone.com/BkY7SD).

Comment: match or search? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-re-search-and-re-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is close, you need to add `\W` character to find the underscore:

```
s = "Generic3(p, [Generic3(g, [Atom('_xyx'), Atom('y'), Atom('z_')]), Atom('x_1'), Generic2(f, [Atom('x'), Atom('y')])])"

r = "(?<=Atom\()\W\w+"

final_data = re.findall(r, s)
```

You can also try this:

```
import re

s = "Generic3(p, [Generic3(g, [Atom('_xyx'), Atom('y'), Atom('z_')]), Atom('x_1'), Generic2(f, [Atom('x'), Atom('y')])])"

new_data = re.findall("Atom\('(.*?)'\)", s)
```

Output:

```
['_xyx', 'y', 'z_', 'x_1', 'x', 'y']
```

Comment: You can use `"Atom\('(.*?)'\)"` and it won't be necessary to post-process the regex matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your suggestion. Please see my recent edit.