# regex doesn't match the required string, except others

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Im new to this wonderful site. Kudos to the team here!
I'm a python beginner!

Im trying to match a string in a file. im using re.match. it does work for other strings in the file except the one im interested into.

file has:

```
Dumping
..
..
Dumped

coordinates (.. ..)
..
..
EOF
```

i tried below script:

```
import re

f1 = open("problem_statment", "r") 
f2 = open("outfile.txt", "w")

for line in f1:
   if re.match("coordinates", line):
      f2.write(line)
```

the outfile doesn't give me the result of 'coordinates' match.., where as if i replace 'coordinates' in above code to 'Dumping', it matches..

Im clueless why it isn't matching 'coordinates'. i want to print whole line..
please guide!

Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce from your input data. Are you sure about the input you've provided here is correct and exactly formatted?

Comment: Yes, its the same input in the file im giving. there is two spaces for coordinates like:  space space coordinates :

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the re module for this. You can just write

```
if 'coordinates' in line:
    f2.write(line)
```

Comment: This will match anywhere in the line, not just start. You need `line.startswith('coordinate')`.

Comment: True. but looking at the file in the example, i don't think that really matters.

Comment: Yes, it worked. but im curios to know why re.match doesnt work here?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the difference between `re.match` and `re.search`. Look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/180993/8382967

Answer (score 0):

The problem with re.match is it only search at beginning of the string. Not in newlines . But your desired string is in newline.

You can use `re.search()` or `re.findall()` method.

```
import re
pattern=r'coordinates.+'
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    print(re.findall(pattern,f.read()))
```

output:

```
['coordinatessss (.. ..)']
```