# Python RegEx not matching but regexr.com is with same expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use the following code to match the text est/(?P[0-9]{4}).

using:
https://regexr.com/

it matches the text, however in python it fails to match the same text with the same expression:

```
[^a-z0-9\/]
```

Here is the code with both conditions. I'm not sure why the regEx will match in regexr.com but not in python unless there is a number sign.

```
import os
import re

#no work
if re.match("[^a-z0-9\/]", "test/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})"):
    print "match"
else:
    print "no match"

#works
if re.match("[^a-z0-9\/]", "#test/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})"):
    print "match"
else:
    print "no match"
```

Comment: Your regex pattern bears little resemblance to the text you are trying to match.  Can you let us know what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Your pattern will match a single character at the beginning of the string that is NOT a (lower case letter OR a digit OR a slash).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)

Comment: You need to use `search()` instead of `match()`. The latter anchors to the start of the string, so your regex becomes `^[^a-z0-9\/]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code snippet:

```
if re.match("[^a-z0-9\/]", "test/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})"):
    print "match"
else:
    print "no match"
```

The pattern `[^a-z0-9\/]` is being applied starting at the beginning of the text.  Hence, it fails because the first letter is `t`, which does not match the pattern.  If you intend to just match a single character corresponding to your original pattern, then you may try the following pattern:

```
.*[^a-z0-9\/].*
```

This pattern will match for both of your example strings.  If you intend to use another pattern, then edit your question and give us more logic.