# Regular expression in python that check if the string just contains letters, numbers and dot(.)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to develop a regular expression for match if a string just contains letters, numbers, space and dot(.) anywhere and with no order.

Like this:

```
hello223 3423.  ---> True
lalala.32 --->True
.hellohow1 ---> True
0you and me = ---> False (it contains =)
@newye ---> False (it contains @)
With, the name of the s0ng .---> False (it start with ,)
```

I am trying with this one but is always returning match:

```
m = re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]+', word)
```

Any idea?

Other way to formulate the question is are there any character diferent of letters, numbers, dot and space?

Thanks in advance

Comment: All or any? E.g. would "A" match?

Comment: @AlexK. Other way to formulate the question is are there any charcater diferent of letters, numbers, dot and space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `$`:

```
re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]+$', word)
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems is working, what does it mean the $?

Comment: @JoanTriay It matchs the end of string. Without it, the match can be in the middle. See `$` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 2):

`re.search()` solution:

```
import re

def contains(s):
    return not re.search(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9. ]', s)

print(contains('hello223 3423.'))    # True
print(contains('0you and me = '))    # False
print(contains('.hellohow1'))        # True
```

Comment: Considering [this `re.match` vs. `re.search`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180993/235908) thread on StackOverflow, I'd prefer `re.search`; its match object also contains the position and content of the mismatch which might be useful for error reporting.