# Regex to get text after a specific word?

Tags: java, regex

How to get text inside quote("asd") after value -> `"name":` like:

```
"name":"John","name":"1-John", "name":"123", "name":"123","name":"A0-0s".
```

I need to get all inside quote(""):

```
John
1-John
123
A0-0s
```

Comment: your question needs clarification

Comment: Look at the javadoc of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and play around with [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex with lookbehind:

```
(?<="name":")[^"]+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/TfkNXE/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex

```
[\w-]+(?=")
```

[Demo at regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/yn1WZK/2)

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you can use is: `\"name\":\"([a-zA-Z0-9--])+\"`. Due to the brackets '()' the required result will be present in the first group of the regex match.

However in case you have multiple combinations in a single string like the one you had in the example, remember to use find() or search() method [and read more about search and match methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match).