# Regex for newline character search in given string in Python

Tags: python

I'm want search newline character in string using regex in python.I don't want to include \r or \n in Message.

I have tried regex which is able to detect \r\n correctly. But when i'm removing \r\n from Line variable. still it prints the error.

```
Line="got less no of bytes than requested\r\n"

if(re.search('\\r|\\n',Line)):
      print("Do not use \\r\\n in MSG");
```

It Should detect \r\n in Line variable which is as a text not the invisible \n.

**It should not print when the Line is Like below:**

```
Line="got less no of bytes than requested"
```

Comment: Use `Line.strip()`. Gives `'got less no of bytes than requested'` as output. No need to use regex then.

Comment: no, use `line.rstrip()` to remove just on the right, not the spaces on the left

Comment: what do you want to achieve? detect end of line or remove end of line?

Comment: It makes sense to use raw strings for regex so you don't need to escape escape characters `r'\r|\n'`

Comment: no need to use raw string for \r or \n. it works without

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well, yes and no. If you match only `\r` or `\n` individually (as indicated in the code), you are right but if you match `\r\n` (as indicated in the text) it matters. However, this inconsistency between text and code makes answering this question a gamble. Also, the `Line` variable holds actual line breaks not the visible characters `\r\n` as indicated in the Text. Finally, knowing about raw strings might help the OP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have noted, you are probably looking for `line.strip()`. But, in case you still want to practice regex, you would use the following code:

```
Line="got less no of bytes than requested\r\n"

# \r\n located anywhere in the string
prog = re.compile(r'\r\n')
# \r or \n located anywhere in the string
prog = re.compile(r'(\r|\n)')


if prog.search(Line):
    print('Do not use \\r\\n in MSG');
```

Comment: because you are wrong in so many cases, 1st to match start and end of the string in regexp there are special characters — ^ and $.
2nd, you should use `search` not `match` if you want to check anywhere in the string

Comment: @maxwell are you happy now that I did it your way?

Comment: You are redefining same `prog` variable → it will match only second regexp

Comment: Yep. They are examples with comments explaining which each do. One should be chosen based on what is needed.

Comment: for authors question the only second is applicable and also you are using regepx groups `()` which are not needed in this case

Comment: It isn't obvious which the author wanted because his regex was the second version, while the output string reflected the first.

Comment: This is not as i want. I want if string explicitly has \r\n character than only it should print  message as Do not use \r\n.

Comment: So the first prog variable is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for newlines, it would probably be better to just remove them. No need to use regex for it, just use `strip`, it will remove all whitespace and newlines from the ends of the string:

```
line = 'got less no of bytes than requested\r\n'
line = line.strip()
# line = 'got less no of bytes than requested'
```

If you want to do it with regex you can use:

```
import re

line = 'got less no of bytes than requested\r\n'
line = re.sub(r'\n|\r', '', line)
# line = 'got less no of bytes than requested'
```

If you insist on checking for the newlines, you can do it like this:

```
if '\n' in line or '\r' in line:
    print(r'Do not use \r\n in MSG');
```

Or the same with regex:

```
import re

if re.search(r'\n|\r', line):
    print(r'Do not use \r\n in MSG');
```

Also: it's advisable to have your Python variables named with [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function.

Try to do this:

```
Import re
Line="got less no of bytes than requested\r\n"
replaced = re.sub('\n','',Line)
replaced = re.sub('\r','',Line)
print replaced
```

Comment: It will DO the action, but question author wants to achieve CHECK (without doing anything); It is good to suggest using different approaches, but only as addition to your answer. Otherwise you actually are not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check for line breaks in the message, you can use the string function `find()`. Note the use of raw text as indicated by the `r` in front of strings. This removes the need to escape the backslash.

```
line = r"got less no of bytes than requested\r\n"
print(line)
if line.find(r'\r\n') > 0:
    print("Do not use line breaks in MSG");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all consider to use strip as many guys here mentioned.

Second, if you want to match newline at ANY position in string use `search` not `match`

[What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)[Here is more about search vs match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)

```
newline_regexp = re.compile("\n|\r")
newline_regexp.search(Line)  # will give u search object or None if not found
```