# Matching pattern from file content and count occurrences

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to read the contents of a file and check if matches list of patterns using regular expression.

File content:

```
google.com
https://google.com
yahoo.com
www.yahoo.com
yahoo
```

My code:

```
import re
file = 'data_files/test_files/content.txt'

regex_1 = re.compile("google")
regex_2 = re.compile("yahoo")

data = open(file, 'r')

print ("Checking Regex 1")
if regex_1.match(data.read()):
    count_c = len(regex_1.findall(data.read()))
    print ("Matched Regex 1 - " + str(count_c))
print("Checking Regex 2")

if regex_2.match(data.read()):
    count_d = len(regex_2.findall(data.read()))
    print("Matched Regex 2 -  " + str(count_d))
else:
    print ("No match found")
```

Output:

```
Checking Regex 1
Checking Regex 2
No match found
```

Couldn't figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The problem here is that he's calling `data.read()` repeatedly, and only the first one reads anything because he doesn't rewind. What does that duplicate have to do with it?

Comment: @Barmar their other problem is that `match` only matches at the *start* of the string anyway. But that's only in the second answer, so maybe not the best target.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Here's the dupe I use for that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `data.read()`, it starts reading from the place in the file where the last call finished. Since the first call reads the entire file (because you didn't specify a limit), all the remaining calls start reading from the end of the file, so they don't read anything.

You should read the file into a variable, and then use that instead of calling `data.read()` repeatedly.

You also need to use `re.search()`, not `re.match()`. See [What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)

```
import re
file = 'data_files/test_files/content.txt'

regex_1 = re.compile("google")
regex_2 = re.compile("yahoo")

with open(file, 'r') as data:

print ("Checking Regex 1")
if regex_1.search(contents):
    count_c = len(regex_1.findall(contents))
    print ("Matched Regex 1 - " + str(count_c))

print("Checking Regex 2")
if regex_2.search(contents):
    count_d = len(regex_2.findall(contents))
    print("Matched Regex 2 -  " + str(count_d))
else:
    print ("No match found")
```