# I want to extract numbers from a list with strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list

I have a list which contains strings: `list = ['string', 'string', 'string', ...]`
Those strings are like: `'NumberDescription 33.3'`
I want to extract only the numbers without the `'NumberDescription' part.`

I've tried it with regex and the filter function with re.match.
But this results in an empty list.

```py
dat_re = re.compile(r'\d+.\d')  
dat_list = list(filter(dat_re.match, list))
```

As I said, I only want the numbers from the list and in a last step, I want to convert the elements of the list into floating numbers.

Comment: 1) Use `re.search`, 2) Escape the dot

Comment: So ```dat_re = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d')``` with ```dat_list = list(filter(dat_re.search, list))```?  
Doesn't work. Search returns the initial list.

Comment: But you filter the list only, you do not extract the values. `dat_list = [dat_re.search(x).group() for x in l if dat_re.search(x)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several points here:

1. Use `re.search` since [`re.match` only searches for the match at the string start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match),
2. Escape the dot as it is a [special regex metacharacter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)
3. You filter the list only with `filter(...)`, you do not extract the values.
4. If you plan to find the `digit+.digit+` first occurrence you may use a regex like `\d+\.\d+`
5. If your items are all in the `string number` format use `s.split()[-1]` to get the number, no need for a regex

Use

```
dat_list = [float(dat_re.search(x).group()) for x in l if dat_re.search(x)]
```

Or, if the format is fixed

```
dat_list = [float(x.split()[-1]) for x in l]
```

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/SDPJDL71716):

```
import re
l = ['string 23.3', 'NumberDescription 33.35']
dat_re = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+')
dat_list = [float(dat_re.search(x).group()) for x in l if dat_re.search(x)]
print(dat_list)
# => [23.3, 33.35]
print([float(x.split()[-1]) for x in l])
# => [23.3, 33.35]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_strings=['1','2','3']
for i in list_strings:
    num_list.append(int(i))
or

list_num = [int(x) for x in list_strings]
```

Check this sample code once.

Answer (score 1):

To extract float value directly from the list:

```
import re
l = ['string 23.3', 'string 33.35', 'string 44.55']
dat_list = list(float(match.group(1)) for match in map(re.compile('(\d+\.\d+)').search, l))
print(dat_list)
```

OUPUT:

```
 [23.3, 33.35, 44.55]
```