# Python re search/match "|" issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

In the Perl era I was a regex freak. I definitely struggle adapting to re. To simplify a big data set I needed to search a "|" character and the only combination that would work was `re.escape'|'` and `re.search` instead of `re.match`

```
import re

x = re.compile((re.escape'|'))
cohort = ['virus_1', 'virus_2|virus_3']

for isolate in cohort:
#   note that re.escape(isolate) fails
    if x.search(isolate):
        print(isolate)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
virus_2|virus_3
```

Okay the above combination works, but `re.match` doesn't work. Also why do I need re.escape('|') and why does re.escape(isolate), i.e. the list element, fail? What am I missing to routinely use re?

Comment: this should not even be valid Python - are you sure you tyed it like this? Python *does not have* special syntax for regex-  they are dealt with by doing function and method calls.

Comment: [What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match) TL;DR: `re.match` is looking for matches **from the start of the string**

Comment: Recall that `re.match` always matches from the beginning of the string. you can fix your regex here with `x = re.compile((r'.*\|'))` You would need to escape the `|` alteration metachracter in Perl too to match the literal `'|'` in a string btw.

Comment: You don't have to use `re.escape`, you can just escape: `re.compile(r'\|')`

Comment: Okay thanks everyone I get it. That was much easier than I thought. Regarding pythonic comprehensions etc... in its disapline specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are two things that likely differ from perl: 
"re.match" in Python have to match the string beginning -
that is: you have to create a regexp which matches from the start 
of the string on. To find a pattern anywhere in the string
you can use `re.search` or `re.findall`.

The other thing indeed has to do with escaping:
the `\` character being used by the Python parser,
before compiling the code, to indicate special control characters
will likely have issues inside plain strings passed to `re` calls.
So Python have a special form of strings, where the quote is prefixed
with an `r`, like `r"regexp_here"`, where the parser does not touch
the `\` character and creates a string object always containing
the literal `\` character. This string is suitable to be passed
as an argument to the various `re` functions.
And then, you just have to escape the `|` with an `\` normally, inside
an `r` marked string:

```py
In [164]: cohort = ['virus_1', 'virus_2|virus_3']                                                                                    

In [165]: [string for string in cohort if re.search(r"\|", string)]                                                                  
Out[165]: ['virus_2|virus_3']

In [166]: [string for string in cohort if re.match(r"^.*?\|", string)]                                                               
Out[166]: ['virus_2|virus_3']

In [167]: [string for string in cohort if re.match(r"\|", string)]                                                                   
Out[167]: []
```