# Limiting phone numbers, regex starts with only a character "+"

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to limit an input of phone numbers to:

- 1-16 digits OR
- A single "+" followed by 1-16 digits.

This is my code

```
txt = "+++854"
x = re.search(str("([\+]{0,1}[0-9]{3,16})|([0-9]{3,16})"), txt)



###^\+[0-9]{1,16}|[0-9]{1,16}", txt) #startswith +, followed by numbers.

if x:
  print("YES! We have a match!")
else:
  print("No match")

# Thatas a match
```

Yet it yields a match. I tried also "^+{0,1}[0-9]{1,16}|[0-9]{1,16}" but despite it works in "https://regex101.com/r/aP0qH2/4" it doesnt work in my code as i think it should work.

Comment: `"(\+?[0-9]{1,16})"` should work as the regex expression, together with `re.match` as described by @ForceBrue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.search) searches for "the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match" and returns the resulting match object. In the string `"+++854"`, the substring `"+854"` matches.

To match *the whole string*, [use `re.match`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match). The documentation has [a section](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#search-vs-match) about the difference between `re.match` and `re.search`.

Comment: "To match the whole string", well, almost. `re.match` matches at the beginning of the string, not necessarily the whole string.

Comment: @L3viathan, right - to match _the whole whole_ string, `^` and `$` should be used in the regex, but with this regex and this input it should be fine to just use `re.match`

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = r"\+?[0-9]{16}"
```

Comment: Its interesting that this also allows "+8+9875" per example. Im going with ([\+]{0,1}[0-9]{3,16})|([0-9]{1,16})