# Retrieve String Regex Pattern Match

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pattern-matching

I have a list `input`:

```
['ICE ERIE', 'ERIE', 'o9 ManGo', 'ManGo SLACKCURRAN 120mL', 'SLACKCURRAN']
```

How can I extract the following string from it:

```
'ManGo SLACKCURRAN 120mL'
```

Another example:

`Input`:

```
['SWANSON', 'Apple Cider Vinegar Food Supplement Supplement mg per tablet DOUBLE STRENGTH FORMULA per tablet 1 NET', 'Cider', 'Vinegar', 'Food Supplement DOUBLE', 'Supplement', '200', 'per', 'tablet', 'DOUBLE', 'TABLETS 1 NET WEIGHT: 62g', '1', 'NET', 'WEIGHT:']
```

`Output`:

```
'TABLETS 1 NET WEIGHT: 62g'
```

My attempt:

```py
import re
l = []
for each in input:   
    elif re.match('^\\d+\\.?\\d*(ounce|fl oz|foot|sq ft|pound|gram|inch|sq in|mL)$',each.lower()):
        l.append(each)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Can you please show more inputs and their outputs?

Comment: Input : ['SWANSON',
 'Apple Cider Vinegar Food Supplement Supplement mg per tablet DOUBLE STRENGTH FORMULA per tablet 1 NET',
 'Cider',
 'Vinegar',
 'Food Supplement DOUBLE',
 'Supplement',
 '200',
 'per',
 'tablet',
 'DOUBLE',
 'TABLETS 1 NET WEIGHT: 62g',
 '1',
 'NET',
 'WEIGHT:']


Output: 'TABLETS 1 NET WEIGHT: 62g'

Comment: consider accepting my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
input_l = ['ICE ERIE', 'ERIE', 'o9 ManGo', 'ManGo SLACKCURRAN 120mL', 'SLACKCURRAN']
reg = re.compile(r'\d*\.?\d+\s*(?:ounce|fl oz|foot|sq ft|pound|gram|inch|sq in|ml)\b', re.I)
print( list(filter(reg.search, input_l)) )
# => ['ManGo SLACKCURRAN 120mL']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/d3xL8c).

**Notes**:

- Use `re.search` to search for matches anywhere inside the string (`re.match` only searches at the string start), see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)
- Remove `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) anchors
- Use a `re.I` flag for case insensitive matching
- `\d*\.?\d+` is a more convenient pattern to match either integer or float numbers as it also supports `.95` like numbers
- End the pattern with a word boundary to match units of measurement as whole words (mind the `r` prefix before the string literal).

Comment: Is there a way to only return  '120mL' instead of  'ManGo SLACKCURRAN 120mL' ?

Comment: @ssr You may do that in many ways, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/KjLiLq).