# Matching an empty paragraph at the end of HTML text

Tags: python, regex

I have written the following pattern to match an empty paragraph at the end of HTML:

https://regex101.com/r/6TNgUV/1

But when I try the following Python code, the result is `None`

```py
html_desc = '</span><p></p><p></p>'
res = re.match('(<p>){1}(\s)*(<br>|<br\/>){0,9}(\s)*(<\/p>){1}(\s)*$', html_desc) 
#  returns None
```

I am not able to understand the issue.

Comment: You need `re.search`, since `re.match` anchors the match to the start. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)

Answer (score 0):

re.match matches starting with the first character, and since your HTML string starts with a  tag, it returns the default case, None, maybe use re.search() instead of re.match()