# Python: Regex Function Parsing Through Email String and Returning Tuple Or Returning ValueError If Input Invalid

Tags: python, regex, match, valueerror

I want to write a function that parses through an email input and returns a tuple with (id, domain).  id is the user name while domain is the domain name.  Email separated by @ character

For example: kyle@asu.edu would parse to ('kyle', 'asu.edu').  But below are some additional constraints on the function:

- username begins with alphabetic character
- domain name ends with alphabetic character
- special characters such as ., -, _, or + are allowed
- no whitespace characters permitted including no leading or trailing whitespaces

So if any of the above rules are violated, then the email input is not considered a valid email address and should raise a ValueError.

Below is my attempted code that doesn't quite work:

```
def email_func(string_input):
    """Parses a string as an email address, returning an (id, domain) pair."""
    ###
    ### YOUR CODE HERE
    regex_parse = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z_+-.]+)@([a-zA-Z.-]+)', string_input) 
    # print (regex_parse)
    
    try:
        return regex_parse.groups()
    
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError ('not a valid email address')
    ###
```

For a simple example it works.

```
email_func('kyle@asu.edu') returns `('kyle', 'asu.edu')` which is correct.
```

Instances where my code doesn't work:

1. For invalid input strings with white spaces I'm not raising a ValueError.  For example:
   `email_func('kyle  @asu.edu')` outputs an error:

   ---> 11  return regex_parse.groups()
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
2. I'm not getting a ValueError for leading white spaces: For example: `email_func('   kyle@asu.edu')` outputs `('kyle', 'asu.edu')`  Same issue with trailing white spaces.
3. How do I specify in my regex that the email can't start or end with a number / has to be alphabetic character?

Comment: Why are you expecting `ValueError`? When `re.search()` can't find a match it returns `None`. `None.groups()` raises `AttributeError`, not `ValueError`.

Comment: hm, I didn't realize that.  I will look into the difference between the two errors.

Answer (score 1):

1. As you can clearly see, calling `regex_parse.groups()` raises `AttributeError`, not `ValueError`, when `regex_parse` is `None`, which is what is returned when `re.search()` can't find a match. So change `except ValueError:` to `except AttributeError:`. Or you could simply use

```
if regex_parse is None: 
    raise ValueError("Not a valid email address")
```

2. You should anchor your regexp so it has to match the entire string, not search for a match anywhere in the string. `r'^([a-zA-Z_+-.]+)@([a-zA-Z.-]+)$'`. `^` matches the beginning, `$` matches the end.
3. Start and end the regexp with `[a-zA-Z]`.
   `r'([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_+-.]*)@([a-zA-Z.-]*[a-zA-Z])'`

Comment: It worked!  thank you :)  Do you have any recommended sites to practice regex problems?

Comment: regex101.com is good. It displays the breakdown of what each part of the regexp means.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your input is only one email address and you need to validate it. So there is no need to use `search`. What you are really looking for is the [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) function.

With small changes to your code, it looks like this:

```
def email_func(string_input):
    """Parses a string as an email address, returning an (id, domain) pair."""
    ###
    ### YOUR CODE HERE
    regex_parse = re.match(r'([a-zA-Z_+-.]+)@([a-zA-Z.-]+)', string_input) 
    # print (regex_parse)
    
    if regex_parse:
        return regex_parse.groups()
    
    else:
        raise ValueError ('not a valid email address')
    ###
```

Comment: ah, yes ... can you explain a bit when would be appropriate to use search vs. match conceptually please?

Comment: It is better explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180993/7769691).

Comment: In general, the "search" function searches the entire string for substrings that match the pattern, it's like Ctrl+F, while the "match" function checks the whole string at once to see if it matches the given pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Below should return a tuple (username, domain). It will raise the except block if any of your constraints are violated. Modify as needed.

```
def email_func(string_input):

    username_template = r'^[a-z][a-z\d_\.+=-]{0,30}@'
    domain_template = r'@\w*\.[a-z]+'

    try:
        username = re.search(username_template, string_input)
        domain = re.search(domain_template, string_input)

        email_tuple = (username.group(0).strip('@'), domain.group(0).strip('@'))

        return email_tuple

    except AttributeError:
        print('please enter a valid email.')
```

To catch the username, the regex below checks to make sure it starts with a latin letter ^[a-z], then for the rest of the username. If ^[a-z] is violated, except block will trigger.

```
username_template = r'^[a-z][a-z\d_\.=-]{0,30}@'
```

To catch domain, the regex below checks to make sure everything proceeding the . is a latin letter and not a digit: .[a-z]+

```
domain_template = r'@\w*\.[a-z]+'
```