# How can I put multiple conditions for detecting a pattern in pandas using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
text

Is it possible to apply [NUM] times
Is it possible to apply [NUM] time
Called [NUM] hour ago
waited [NUM] hours
waiting [NUM] minute
waiting [NUM] minutes???
Are you kidding me !
Waiting?
```

I want to be able to detect pattern that have `"[NUM] time" or "[NUM] times" or "[NUM] minute" or "[NUM] minutes" or "[NUM] hour" or "[NUM] hours"`. Also, if it has `"!" (or more than one !)` or `"??" (at least two ?)`.

So the result would look like this:

```
text.                                  available

Is it possible to apply [NUM] times.   True
Is it possible to apply [NUM] time.    True
Called [NUM] hour ago                  True
waited [NUM] hours                     True
waiting [NUM] minute                   True
waiting [NUM] minutes???               True
Are you kidding me !                   True
Waiting?                               False
I didn't like it                       False
```

So I want something like this but don't know how to put all these condition together:

```
df["available"] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: re.match(r'[\!* | \?+ | [NUM] time | [NUM] hour | [NUM] minute]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.contains` with a regex:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':["Is it possible to apply [NUM] times","Is it possible to apply [NUM] time","Called [NUM] hour ago","waited [NUM] hours","waiting [NUM] minute","waiting [NUM] minutes???","Are you kidding me !","Waiting?", "I didn't like it"]})
df['available'] = df['text'].str.contains(r'\[NUM]\s*(?:hour|minute|time)s?\b|!|\?{2}', regex=True)
## => df['available']
#     0     True
#     1     True
#     2     True
#     3     True
#     4     True
#     5     True
#     6     True
#     7    False
#     8    False
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fBxIUU/1). *Details*:

- `\[NUM]` - `[NUM]` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:hour|minute|time)`  - a non-capturing group matching `hour`, `minute` or `time`
- `s?` - an optional `s`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `|` - or
- `!` - a `!` char
- `|` - or
- `\?{2}` - two question marks.

Comment: Do you happen to know why the same code does not work when I am using a text rather than the text inside a data frame? `text="Been on hold for [NUM] minutes at that number, AFTER it wouldn't let me cancel the reservation."` and  then `available = re.match('r\[NUM]\s*(?:hour|minute|time|number|hr|Hr)s?\b|!{2}|\?{2}', text)` the `available` is NONE. Sorry if I did not open a new question as Im new in `regex` I thought this may be easy question and I received many negative points :((((

Comment: @sariii Correct, you would get lots of downvotes on such a question. The answer is "use `re.search`". See [What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/180986/3832970)

Comment: yea I figured if I post that question my score will down to -1000 :))). Thanks for sharing the link. However, neither `search` nor `match` do not return any reasonable output. Both returned `None`. The way I understood the difference between them is just for the cases where either `new line` or `^` exist in the sentence. However, my case is just one line so I think both `match` and `search` should be able to do the job. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @sariii Your *regex* works, you just made a typo by moving the raw string literal `r` prefix into the string literal itself. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/KUTevm).

Comment: Ahhhh that's true, Thanks sooo0 much :)