# How can I use regex to match sub-string start by words (not included) to the end of string, and keep non-greedy at same time?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find a sub-string that starts with words `(\d月|\d日)` (not included in result) and to the end of the string, at the same time, keep the sub-string shortest (non-greedy). for example,

```
str1 = "秋天9月9日长江工程完成"
res1 = re.search(r'(\d月|\d日).*', str1).group() #return 9月9日长江工程完成
```

I want to return the result like `长江工程完成`,
for another example,

```
str2 ="秋天9月9日9日长江工程完成"
```

it should get same results like previous one

thus I tried these several methods, but all return un-expected results, please give me some suggestion...

```
res1 = re.search(r'(?:(?!\d月|\d日))(?:\d月|\d日)', str1).group() #return 9月
res1 = re.search(r'(?:\d月|\d日)((?:(?!\d月|\d日).)*?)', content).group()  #return 9月
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return false"?

Comment: Please explain more about the format. Do you want any number of groups like `\d月` and `\d日`? or just two? Can it be `日` first and `月` second? [More examples would help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418442/10295729)

Comment: @decorator-factoryde thanks for reply and I rewrite it, please have a look

Comment: Remove last `?`. Use `re.search(r'(?:\d月|\d日)((?:(?!\d月|\d日).)*)$', content).group(1)`, see https://ideone.com/k6wuVO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture the rest of the string, surround `.*` with a group.

To capture one or more of the same pattern, you can use the `+` operator.

```py
import re

content = "9月9日9月长江工程完成"
match = re.match(r'(?:\d月|\d日)+(.*)', content)
print(match[1])
```

Output:

```
长江工程完成
```

---

`(?:(?!\d月|\d日))(?:\d月|\d日)`

This pattern only captures the initial words, because you don't capture the rest as a group. (Also, it only allows for exactly two occurences).

---

`(?:\d月|\d日)((?:(?!\d月|\d日).)*?)`

This pattern requires only matches strings that look like this:
`9月4日a6日b0月x` - probably not what you need

---

P.S. Make sure you pick right function from the `re`: `match`, `search` or `fullmatch` (see [What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)). You said that you need the whole string needs to start with the given words, so `match` or `fullmatch`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, consider more general situation, what if some words in front of d月|\d日? I rewrite the content of str1 and str2, please have a look. and by the way, did match means searching from the beginning position and search from any position of string?