# Regex pattern no working in Python but on RegExr?

Tags: python, python-re

From the strings in `data`, I'm trying to capture "FUND", respectively "FUND*", "Total", and "Rest" in a first group, the following thereafter floating point number, including its prefixed sign, in a second group, and the contents between the parenthesis or brackets in a third group with my regex `pattern` in Python 3.

```py
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [
        "    - ‍♂️ FUND  +145.00 [ 2 reached]",
        "    -  FUND*  +25.00 (⟶ Mar. 75.00/300)",
        "    -  FUND   +17.49 (⟶ Apr. 300.00)",
        "    -  FUND   +36.21 (⟶ May 250.00)",
        "    -  FUND  +150.00 (⟶ Jul. 1500.00)",
        "    -  FUND  +115.00 (⟶ Sep. 1000.00)",
        "    - ✒️ FUND   +11.30",
        "      ----------------",
        "         Total  500.00",
        "         Rest     0.00"
    ]
    
    pattern = r"(\w+)\s+([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)\s?([:\(\[].+[:\)\]])?"
    for d in data:
        match = re.match(pattern, d)
        print(match)
```

I've tested the `pattern` on RegExr with the exact same data, and it works fine on the website. However, in Python `match` is always `None`?

Do I need to escape some characters in the `pattern` that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match` checks if a string matches the regex from the beginning of the string, it does *not* search for the regex inside the string, so:

```py
re.match("bc", "abc") # -> None
```

The function you probably had in mind is `re.search`:

```py
re.search("bc", "abc") # -> <re.Match object; span=(1, 3), match='bc'>
```